# how to develop for a nokia phone?

Tags: qt, symbian, nokia

i'm a little bit confused about all the different nokia SDK, what do i need to develop apps with c++?
the nokia QT sdk oder the nokia symbian^3 SDK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either one. Obviously, if you want to develop Qt-based Symbian apps you will need the Nokia Qt SDK. However, Nokia has clearly and repeatedly stated that Qt is the future of Symbian development going forward, so for all new code, use the Nokia Qt SDK.